# Lock payment type in database for WooCommerce, or delete PayPal, WordPress site

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, paypal

I look after a WordPress site FOC which uses WooCommerce to take orders, the only valid method is to pay on arrival and all money goes to a local hospice. lately and intermittently the payment type has been switched to Paypal and an unknown email address.

assuming the site has been hacked both I and the the hosting provider have checked it and nothing seems unusual. Worddefence is also active on the site.

To prevent this until we can figure out who and how, is there a way to lock the database key that controls this? if so which table and key? or is there a way to delete PayPal from the system?

WordPress is using MySQL

If the above is not possible is there a hook I can call before payment and check payment type, and then cancel if its Paypal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the following on a WooCommerce blog post to enable PayPal Standard:
add_filter( 'woocommerce_should_load_paypal_standard', '__return_true' );

Changing it to the following has stopped PayPal Standard from loading:
add_filter( 'woocommerce_should_load_paypal_standard', '__return_false' );